# how to deactivate vc-git in GNU Emacs?

Tags: git, version-control, emacs, magit

I created a Git repository for the folder with my Emacs text files, then installed git.el and Magit.

Emacs seems to have slowed down a lot, and I keep seeing the message `loading vc-git...done` in the minibuffer.

Am I right in thinking that interacting with Git is what's slowing down Emacs?

I don't actually need to use Emacs to interact with Git, I usually just use GitHub anyway. I removed references to git.el and magit.el from my .emacs file, but I'm still getting the message.

How do I disable vc-git in Emacs so I can work quickly again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one disable vc-git in emacs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748814/how-does-one-disable-vc-git-in-emacs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I keep this in my `.emacs`:

```
(setq vc-handled-backends ())
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to disable `vc-git` specifically, but since I never use version control through Emacs, it works for me.