# How does one enable vc-git in emacs?

Tags: emacs, version-control, elisp

I disabled vc-git using [`(setq vc-handled-backends ())`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6190338/1309352). But now how can I reenable it?

These haven't worked:

- `(require 'vc-git)`
- `(require 'vc)`

Getting `vc-handled-backends` back to it's default would be preferred.

Plus how could I get it back to default without using something like [`(setq vc-handled-backends (quote (...)))`](https://superuser.com/a/445928/213198)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this variable is a customizable user option, Emacs remembers what its default value was, so you can revert it in a running instance.

`C-h v vc-handled-backends RET` then click `customize` (or `M-x customize-variable RET vc-handled-backends RET`).

Comment: Any way of doing this entirely through `eval`?

Comment: I suspect there's probably a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do, but a direct answer is: `(setq vc-handled-backends (eval (car (get 'vc-handled-backends 'standard-value))))`.